# I have an error "Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8)". This is what I can find in my project (ECLISPE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api

[image]

I try to make a 'done' button at my app. (according to a book)

At first, when I make a new app 'Hellow wordl!', there was no problem

but, now I add some lines in "**TestAndroidMainActivity.java**",

it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Can u paste ur code here

Comment: Basically this comes when u r using a particular api which is nt ter in the lower version sdk

Comment: you can try increasing the minsdkversion in gradle from 8 to 11, but if you are bent on supporting devices less than api 11, then you will be restricted to use only limited resources from the sdk because of this restriction.

Comment: Just change the minsdk to 11 in ur manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that some of the methods you've used in your code requires minimum SDK version 11. You can change the minSDK to 11 in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the minsdkversion in gradle from 8 to 11, but if you are bent on supporting devices using api version less 11, then you will be restricted to use only limited resources from the sdk because of this restriction. By changing from minsdkversion 8 to 11 you won't be losing much customer base, because a very small percentage of the android device users population is using devices that has OS version below Android gingerbread 2.2, hell you can even set your minsdkversion to 16 and cover more than 90% of the android user base

Answer (score 0):

Just go into you AndroidManifest.xml

over there change the values for **android:minSdkVersion** and **android:targetSdkVersion**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bd.redrover"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    /// MAKE YOUR CHANGES OVER HERE
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.SpalshScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>



</manifest>
```

Let me know if this works! :)

Comment: your code means that i need to change minSdkVersion to upper number than 8, right?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your error line itself.
The only thing it requires is higher level of SDK and you can change it from your manifest file easily. 
Good luck!!